# SAS - proc import with excel file, dbms not valid

Tags: excel, sas

I have a .xls excel file (Microsoft Excel 97-2003 Worksheet) which I want to import to SAS. So I used:

```
proc import datafile = "C:\Users\***\***\data.xls" 
        out = data dbms = EXCEL;
run;
```

However I get a following error:

> ERROR: DBMS type EXCEL not valid for import.

I have tried different DBMS (I do not really get the difference in many cases, but just took a guess with EXCEL97, EXCEL4, EXCEL5, XLS). None of these worked. Do you have any idea how to deal with that?

The few first columns look like below:

```
id      status      start       end         duration   browser    browserversion   country              Age
51      complete    03/08/2016  03/08/2016  0:21:57    Chrome     65.0             1                    51
133     complete    03/08/2016  03/08/2016  0:10:07    Chrome     58.0             1                    18
1002    complete    03/08/2016  03/08/2016  0:17:57    Chrome     58.0             1                    40
```

Comment: DO you have a license for SAS/Access to PC files?

Comment: How can I check that? If it is a kind of application (like sas enterprise guide) then probabli not

Comment: Run `proc setinit; run;`

Comment: Ok, so I don't.

Comment: Save the sheet as a CSV file and read it using a data step.

Answer (score 5):

You need to have a licence. Run PROC SETINIT and see if you have this product licensed.

```
---SAS/ACCESS Interface to PC Files
```

If not then save the excel file as a CSV file and read it using a data step.  It is really easy.

```
data myfile ;
  infile "C:\Users\***\***\myfile.csv" dsd firstobs=2 truncover ;
  length varfirst 8 var2 $30 .... varlast $5 ;
  input varfirst -- varlast ;
run;
```

Add an INFORMAT and FORMAT statement for any variables that need them, like dates.  Normal character or numeric variables do NOT need either an INFORMAT or a FORMAT for SAS to be able to read or display them properly.

Comment: That is helpful. However, I have around 200 columns so specifying their length one after one is rather tedious. I have tried to use proc import with csv file, but it reads all in one column and one row with data separated by semicolon. In Csv file I have data in separate column. And here is what I used `proc import datafile = "C:\Users\***\***\my_file.csv" out = data dbms = csv replace; 
run;` Is there a way to fix it?

Comment: If the file is well structured then 200 columns is not really a problem. For example you might just have an ID variable and 199 numeric variables.  `length id $10 var1-var199 8;`

Comment: You need to tell SAS what delimiter to use. Sounds like you want to use `dbms=dlm` and add the `delimiter=';';` statement.

Comment: `proc import datafile = "C:\Users\***\myfile.csv" out = data dbms = dlm replace; 
delimiter = ';' ;
run;` didn't work. Also my file contains columns with different length (ex. there are ids of length 2 or 3 or even 4), so I don't think data step will do here. Really appreciate the effort though!

Comment: If you want help with syntax to read your file post a few lines of the text.  You probably don't need to show all 200 columns.  Either edit the question or start a new one.  Defining the lengths for 200 variables would have taken a fraction of the time you have spent trying to get SAS to guess at what is in the file. You can just copy the headers from your data file and edit it into a `length` statement. Numeric variables are always length 8 and for character just make them longer than you expect to need. You can change it later and re-run.

Comment: I doubt that a CSV file looks like what you have posted. What you posted has either spaces or tabs between the values.  Do NOT open the CSV file in Excel. Open it in a text editor, like Notepad or SAS program editor. Then you can see the actual content.

Comment: You do have some date and time columns. If you want to read those correctly then you will need to use informats and attach formats so they display nicely.  But you could start by just reading them as character to see if you can get the data into a data step.

Answer (score 2):

Please Try Dbms = xlsx or dbms = xls. For older Microsoft office xls engine works.

Comment: As I mentioned earlier I had tried XLS. Now I gave it a go with XLSX. Neither of them works.

Comment: The xlsx was it for me. Thanks. Much appreciated, if I am using SAS University, will that capability at some point?